# Возможно ли создание в проекте Jira зависимого справочника 4-х уровней?

Tags: java, jira, confluence

Рассматриваем Jira в кач-ве решения для проекта.
Есть потребность использовать в проекте для классификации задач 4х уровненный справочник, где нижестоящие уровни зависят от вышестоящих. Чем ниже уровень, тем меньше абстракция.

```
level1: Type
level2: Product
level3: Problem
level4: Case
```

Насколько это реально реализовать в Jira. Ответа в документации нет.

Answer (score 0):

В плане родительских-дочерних задач Jira предлагает [3 уровня](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confeval/jira-software-evaluator-resources/jira-software-hierarchy) в проекте:

- Эпик
- Задача (на этом же уровне История)
- Подзадача

Для искусственного увеличения количества уровней можно использовать плагины вроде [Structure](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/34717/structure-project-management-at-scale) или [Portfolio](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212136/advanced-roadmaps-formerly-portfolio).

Но тут нужно понимать, как именно уровни должны зависеть от вышестоящих. Может, есть смысл приспособить компоненты или каскадный выбор внутри самой задачи.